# jQuery: adjusting width+height later in fancyBox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

So i have this fancybox with these configurations:

```
            $("a#uploadImage").fancybox({
            'titleShow'     : false,
            'width':    560,
            'height':   120,
            'autoDimensions': false,
            'overlayOpacity': 0.6
            });
```

Now i wish to expand the height with 230 and the width with 700, when you click on the next button INSIDE the fancybox. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its very much possible with css property

$("a#uploadImage").css('width',caculatedwidth);
$("a#uploadImage").css('height',caculatedheight);

Comment: tried this: $("a#uploadImage").css('width', 560); $("a#uploadImage").css('height', 700); didnt work

Comment: it should work  see the below link http://api.jquery.com/css/. can you show your html please